# Integrate .chm in my project

Tags: wpf, chm

I have help files in my project. I've tried to open it localy by this way and it works :

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Users\Sheamus\Documents\myCHM.chm");
```

I have to integrate it in the application, so I've placed the .chm in my project, as a resource, but I can't open it by this way, VS tells me it doesn't find the file :

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"pack://application:,,,/MyLibrary;component/Help/myCHM.chm");
```

Do you have an idea ?

Answer (score 1):

First method seems good for me. Incluye your chm in your project as a existent file, and make sure you have set the *Build* property to Context, and the *Copy to Output Directory* to Always, or Copy if Newer. Then in runtime, you can locate the file with something like

```
System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Help.chm")
```

If you want something a little more complex than launch a file, you could try [Easy Help](http://peteohanlon.wordpress.com/2009/05/01/easy-help-with-wpf/)